# How to use pthread_mutex_t and pthread_spinlock_t in the multi-process environment？

Tags: linux, locking, pthreads, shared-memory, systems-programming

If I want to use `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_spinlock_t` in the multi-process environment, I have some questions below.

1. Must I need to initialize the structure in the shared memory or use mmap()?
2. If I initialize the structure in the shared-memory and set the attr PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE, what would happen?

Comment: Ever tried to write some test cases to test it?